# jQuery removeClass based on ID?

Tags: jquery

So right now I'm doing this:

```
$(".radio_visible").hide().removeClass("radio_visible");
```

But what I'd like to be able to do is remove all of the `radio_visible` classes if it's within a specific ID. Sort of like this:

```
$(".radio_visible").hide().removeClass("#payment_fields .radio_visible");
```

So is there another jQuery function I should be looking at to pull that off?

Comment: Do you want to hide all elements with the "radio_visible" class but only remove the class from the element with a specific ID? Or do you want to only hide the element with the id "payment_fields"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do:

```
$("#payment_fields .radio_visible").hide().removeClass("radio_visible");
```

Comment: Dangit. So obvious. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
$('#payment_fields *.radio_visible').hide().removeClass('radio_visible');
```